# Error: Object not associated with an object identity

Tags: 2013, csom, jsom

After newly creating a content type via JSOM, I'm getting the following error when calling `contentType.update()` or `context.load(contentType)`:

> The object is not associated with an object identity or the object identity is invalid.

Can you explain what this means, and how to avoid it?

I know (by inspecting the source of `sp.js`) this is happening because `contentType.get_path().$d_0` is `false`, but I don't know what that means, or how to make it true again.

```
// excerpt from SP.ClientQueryInternal, where the error is thrown
// a is the content type in this case
if (!a.get_path() || !a.get_path().$d_0)
    throw Error.create(SP.ResResources.getString("NoObjectPathAssociatedWithObject"));
```

However, I've tracked when that value becomes false.

Here's how I'm creating the content type. This is where the `$d_0` property becomes `false`.

```
// Create the content type
ctInfo = new SP.ContentTypeCreationInformation()
// Set up the info
// ...
contentType = contentTypes.add(ctInfo);
contentType.update()
context.load(contentTypes)
context.load(contentType) // This works, although it is superfluous
// contentType.get_path().$d_0 is true at this point
context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, failureHandler)
// contentType.get_path().$d_0 is now false; this is before the success handler is called!
context.load(contentType)   // Fails here (although it is superfluous at this point)
context.executeQueryAsync()
```

After `successHandler` returns, `$d_0` is still `false`, and `contentType.update()` or `context.load(contentType)` still fails (e.g. while trying to add site columns to `contentType`.

Comment: What is your "contentTypes"? Is it a "contentTypeCollection"?
You just need to load the collection "contentTypes". No need of contentType.update() and context.load(contentType).

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm actually trying to update the contentType after adding site columns to it, but I've removed that piece to narrow down the scope of the bug.

Comment: Are you trying to get the newly created content type?

Comment: No, I'm not calling `getByTitle` or such. I've been using the reference returned by `contentTypes.add`. This has worked in the past, and I'm not sure what's different now.

Comment: why have you loaded context.load(contentType) twice? and then executed? Update your code please.

Comment: @harshalgite I added the first load to see if it works before calling `executeQuery`. I added the second load to see if it works immediately after. The first succeeds, and the second fails, and both are unnecessary, except for debugging purposes.

Comment: Second will fail because the code will go into successHandler or failureHandler. What are your trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to add site columns to the contentType later on, which is why I'm re-loading the contentType then. That happens after the success handler runs.

Comment: Add site-columns to the content type inside the successHandler. Thats the ideal way to do it.

Comment: @harshalgite Thanks for your input! I'm getting the same error in the success handler, although I've had that work in other cases. I must be missing something here.

Comment: Try creating new context and fetching the content type by id or name and then add the site column. Create the context using URL.

Comment: @harshalgite Thanks for your tips and suggestions. As I dug deeper, I realized the issue was in my `getContentType` function, which I was using to calculate the parent content type during the creation process for the new content type. This bug was very hard to track down, so hopefully this question will help someone else.

Comment: @harshalgite Looking back on this, your suggestions would be imminently more useful to someone else looking at my question than my answer is. Do you think it is worthwhile to combine them into a single answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. There was a problem with the way I was created the content type, but that error was swallowed. SharePoint did actually return an error message for the original issue, aside from this obscure error message:

> Invalid request.

Unfortunately, the issue wasn't in the abbreviated code I posted. I was setting the `parentContentType` property of the `ctInfo` object to an empty array `[]`, which is definitely an invalid content type!

I should have caught this, of course, but my success handler was being called anyway, due to another issue; and I am re-using the same failure-handler for many requests, making it even harder to pin down where "Invalid Request" was coming from.

---

Here is the line in the request (to create the content-type) which was incorrect:

```
<Property Name="ParentContentType" Type="Array"/>
```

Here is the entire request which was generated to create the content type.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="15.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
  <Actions>
    <ObjectPath Id="288" ObjectPathId="287"/>
    <ObjectIdentityQuery Id="289" ObjectPathId="287"/>
    <Query Id="290" ObjectPathId="267">
      <Query SelectAllProperties="true">
        <Properties/>
      </Query>
      <ChildItemQuery SelectAllProperties="true">
        <Properties/>
      </ChildItemQuery>
    </Query>
  </Actions>
  <ObjectPaths>
    <Property Id="267" ParentId="38" Name="ContentTypes"/>
    <Method Id="287" ParentId="267" Name="Add">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter TypeId="{168f3091-4554-4f14-8866-b20d48e45b54}">
          <Property Name="Description" Type="String">IPAC Program Proprosal</Property>
          <Property Name="Group" Type="String">IPAC</Property>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="Null"/>
          <Property Name="Name" Type="String">IpacProprosal</Property>
          <Property Name="ParentContentType" Type="Array"/>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Method>
    <Identity Id="38" Name="740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:4b2682a6-2589-4acd-a6b4-37538cf731bd:web:7eeee2d4-e551-44a0-aa71-b045b67c9e87"/>
  </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

Here is SharePoint's response:

```
[
{
"SchemaVersion":"15.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"15.0.4763.1000","ErrorInfo":{
"ErrorMessage":"Invalid request.","ErrorValue":null,"TraceCorrelationId":"a2a5189e-834c-20bc-026e-db3059cb3269","ErrorCode":-1,"ErrorTypeName":"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
},"TraceCorrelationId":"a2a5189e-834c-20bc-026e-db3059cb3269"
}
]
```